# How to only load data with the highest value in one of the flat file column?

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have the following flat file:

```
ColumnA              Quantity              BatchID
1                          10                            100
1                              10                           200
2                              20                           100
2                              20                           200
3                              30                           100
3                              30                           200
```

How can I only load the data from the highest BatchID, ie BatchID 200 to my SQL Server database ?

In the above example, I want to load this data to my database:

```
ColumnA              Quantity              BatchID
1                              10                           200
2                              20                           200
3                              30                           200
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StackOverflow isn't about providing solutions, but about solving specific problems where the OP has already tried something. Please keep that in mind when posting questions.

With that said, there are two potential solutions:

1. Load the data into a temp table and then INSERT using a SELECT that has an inline view that SELECTs by the MAX value. An inline view must be used because you cannot use an aggregate in the predicate, so you have to run a separate SELECT to get the max value - alternatively you can break it out into a Common Table Expression (CTE) and SELECT from that.
2. Perform in-line within SSIS. First, sort the column based on BatchId and Quantity (I assume that this is how you sort by). Then use a script task to store the quantity in a variable. Now, run over each row and compare the incoming value with the stored value: if it is greater than, then you can set a new BIT column called IsMaxValue. From there, perform a Conditional Split to send the row with the IsMaxValue == 1 to the database.

Comment: Thank you for your help